# How to incorporate PHP code toegether with HTML code in a javascript script?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that dynamically adds and removes elements.
I also have a drop down that is populated dynamically.

How can I put the two together?

Here is the code that I use to dynamically add and remove elements:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

  var maxRows = 100;
  var x = 1;

  var phpcode = '<?php $stmt=$author_of_book->read_author_of_section(); $num=$stmt->rowCount(); if($num>0){ echo '<select name="author_of_book[]" id="author_of_book-list">'; echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>'; while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ extract($row); echo '<option value="' .$row["author_of_book"]. '"data-author_of_book_id="' .$row["author_of_book_id"]. '">' .$row["author_of_book"]. '</option>'; } echo "</select>"; } ?>';

  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#book_table").append("<tr><td>" + phpcode + "</td><td><select name='book_title[]' id='book_title-list'><option value='0' disabled selected>Select</option></select></td><td><button type='button' id='remove' class='btn btn-danger'>Remove</span></button></td></tr>");
    }
  });

    $("#book_table").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

The idea is that a user can add as many books as they wish. 
When a user selects a particular author the next drop down will list the titles of all of the author's books.

Using this PHP code I dynamically populate a drop down list based on the previous drop down selection:

I have created two class files.

```php
    class author_of_book{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "author_of_book";

    // object properties
    public $author_of_book_id;
    public $author_of_book;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function read_author_of_book(){

        $query = "SELECT author_of_book_id, author_of_book
                FROM " . $this->table_name . "
                ORDER BY author_of_book";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
     }
    }
```

Here is the other class file:

```php
    class book_title{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "book_title";

    // object properties
    public $book_title_id;
    public $author_of_book_id;
    public $book_title;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function read_book_title(){

        $query = "SELECT book_title_id, author_of_book_id, book_title
                FROM " . $this->table_name . "
                WHERE author_of_book_id = :author_of_book_id
                ORDER BY book_title";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // santize
        $this->author_of_book_id=strtoupper(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->author_of_book_id)));

        // bind value
        $stmt->bindParam(":author_of_book_id", $this->author_of_book_id);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }

    }
```

I also have this php code for json file

```php
    // set json headers
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $author_of_book_id=isset($_GET['author_of_book_id']) ? $_GET['author_of_book_id'] : die('Author ID not found.');

    // include database and object files
    include_once 'config/database.php';
    include_once 'objects/book_title.php';

    // instantiate database and object
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $book_title = new book_title($db);

    $book_title->author_of_book_id = $author_of_book_id;
    $stmt = $book_title->book_title();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($results);
```

Then in the form I use this code to render the drop down list with the help of javascript

```php
    // include database and object files
    include_once 'config/database.php';
    include_once "objects/author_of_book.php";

    // instantiate database and objects
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    $qfs_section = new author_of_book($db);

    $page_title = "Book Form";
    include_once "layout_head.php";
?>
    <table id="book_table">
          <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th><button type="button" id="add">Add</button></th>
          </tr>
        </table>

    <?php
    include_once "layout_foot.php";
```

And last is is JavaScript code to make the dynamic drop down work

```js
    //Author
    $(document).ready(function() {
     // detect change of dropdown
     $("#author_of_book-list").change(function() {
    // get id of selected author
    var author_of_book_id = $(this).find(':selected').data('author_of_book_id');
    // set json url
    var json_url = "book_title_type_json.php?author_of_book_id=" + author_of_book_id;
    // get json data
    jQuery.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
      // empty contents of book_title dropdown
      $("#book_title-list").html("");
      $("#book_title-list").append("<option value='0' disabled selected>Select</option>");
      // put new dropdown values to book_title dropdown
      jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $("#book_title-list").append('<option value="' + val.book_title + '"data-book_title_id="' + val.book_title_id + ' ">' + val.book_title + '</option>')
      });
    });
    });
    });
```

My problem is that every time I incorporate my drop down code into the dynamic add-remove code something goes wrong. I was able to make the first drop down to work but not the second one.

Comment: There is a thing as too much code in a question.  Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use AJAX for that. See, what PHP interpreter does is to produce HTML and JavaScript as a string and send it that way to the browser. Therefore, in order for JavaScript to get values stored in PHP, it needs to communicate back with the server. That's what the XMLHttpRequest object is there in Vanilla JavaScript, or the JQuery AJAX is there for.
Or, if you just want the PHP code embedded into JavaScript to be executed **before** the JavaScript is sent to the browser, you can put it without the quotation marks. Like I've done [here](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/SVG-Pacman/blob/master/pacman.php):

```
var highscore=<?php echo "\"".$highscore."\";"; ?>
```

Comment: though I am not sure I understand yet, but I suspect the problem lies in the second script that calls for data to be filled in the second drop down. On the first drop down, it is working as intended, it is being filled with data from the database using php. The problem is when there is an item that was selected on the first drop down, it should active the second drop down to list down its corresponding data.

Comment: another theory is it wont work because the code was triggered or created by javascript itself, and javascript cannot trigger a javascript-triggered element.